# How to midi map device pads to drum rack pads across multiple drum racks in ableton

Tags: midi, ableton-live, ableton

Seems like this should be really simple, but when I am midi mapping controls, I cant figure out how to map a device pad to a chosen drum sample. I want to play samples from 2 different drum rack by midi mapping device pads to specific samples in each rack.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to group the drum racks together and use zones to control which notes go to which drum rack.

https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/instrument-drum-and-effect-racks/#18-5-zones